# What does "Deals Bonus Explosive Damage" mean in quantitative terms?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is extra damage done by explosive weapon calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85308/how-is-extra-damage-done-by-explosive-weapon-calculated)

I come across weapons regularly that state "Deals Bonus Explosive Damage" but don't have any additional information about what exactly that means in terms of damage output. Does anyone how exactly what these do?

Here's an example:
[image: explosive damage example]

Comment: (As I haven't answered the earlier question) I'm not 100% sure what the factor is here. I've seen much smaller muplication factors (more like 50% per shot) than the proposed dupe indicates. I'd research but I don't have explosive weapons with my at the moment.